# Fun with C macros

Tags: c, macros

Let's say I have a function macro in C called `FOO`. There are also two macros called `BAR1` and `BAR2`, which are basically two flavors of the same macro. I'd like to write a macro `BAR` such that it expands to `BAR1` in functions which invoke `FOO` somewhere before the use of `BAR` and to `BAR2` otherwise. So for example:

```
void func1(void)
{
    FOO();
    ...
    BAR();
}
```

would be equivalent to

```
void func1(void)
{
    FOO();
    ...
    BAR1();
}
```

while this function:

```
void func2(void)
{
    BAR();
}
```

would be equivalent to

```
void func2(void)
{
    BAR2();
}
```

I'd like to avoid introducing global variables or doing additional checks at runtime. Is this even possible?

Comment: Not if `BAR1` and `BAR2` can be absolutely arbitrary macros, since you can't dynamically condition `#define` on macro expansion. But, if you tell us what `BAR1` and `BAR2` are, essentially, then there might be a way to do it by exploiting the similarity in structure.

Comment: Are you gearing up for making an IOCCC submission?

Comment: @nneonneo: `FOO()` checks if a pointer is NULL. `BAR1()` dereferences that pointer, while `BAR2()` does not.

Comment: @user2656304: I'd actually trust the compiler to optimize that. A `NULL` check is very cheap, and most compilers can skip redundant `NULL` checks with optimizations turned on.

Comment: @nneonneo: thanks! The problem is that the pointer variable isn't even declared in some functions. I could introduce a global variable with the same name and set it to `NULL`, but that would be rather inelegant.

Comment: Ah, so `BAR2` doesn't use the variable at all in that case? I wonder why you are using a macro for this...seems like it would be easier to just do the checks on the variable explicitly and leave the macro as small as possible.

Comment: @user2656304: Inelegant? Curious word, given that you are willing to abuse the precompiler in such a way.

Comment: My advise is to explicitly use `BAR1()` or `BAR2()` but write them in such a way that the wrong version won't compile. That way you cannot get it wrong, but you do not obfuscate the code with hard to follow hacks.

Comment: @nneonneo: It would only clutter the code. Now I just use `BAR2()` before `FOO()` and `BAR1()` after (`FOO()` returns from the function if the pointer turns out to be `NULL`).

Comment: @rodrigo: how would you do that? BAR1 won't compile when the pointer variable isn't in scope, but other than that...?

Comment: @rodrigo: I think my solution would have been quite elegant, it's just that C does not make it easy to do such things.

Comment: @nneonneo: I would actually be willing to go with the dummy global variable solution, but it creates the risk of dereferencing an uninitialized pointer when `BAR()` is used in a function before the pointer is initialized.

Comment: Simple solution: always initialize your pointers to NULL. You can also catch such bad usage with the appropriate compiler warning flags.

Comment: @user2656304: "C does not make it easy to do such things": Indeed. If you really want to do this and keep a minimum of elegance, just use C++ (keyword: destructors).

Comment: @rodrigo: yeah, I would have used something different altogether if I had the choice.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: NO. The C precompiler knows nothing about function limits, so even if you managed to modify the `BAR` macro as you want it, that would not be limited to the current function anyway.

Now, if you are willing, you can add some checks to the `BAR` macro. And those checks can be written to be resolved at compile time, so no runtime overhead results.

For example:

```
extern char _sentinel_[2];

#define FOO() char _sentinel_;

#define BAR() if (sizeof(_sentinel_) == 1) BAR1() else BAR2()
```

The trick is that the look up of variable `_sentinel_` will resolve the global variable or the local one, depending on the use of `FOO()`. And since the condition in the `if` is a compiler constant, the compiler will optimize out the other branch.

Comment: There's the `__FUNCTION__` macro.

Comment: @user2656304: what are you going to do with `__FUNCTION__`? `strcmp` it in the preprocessor??

Comment: @user2656304: `__FUNCTION__`, and `__func__` in C99, are variables, not macros, IIRC. And the reason is precisely that the precompiler knows nothing about functions. The confusion arises because `__FILE__` and __LINE__` are macros, but the precompiler does know about files and lines...

Comment: This means `FOO` must be used in the beginning of a function. A definition in the middle isn't legal before C99, and a definition within a block will not work as required.

Answer (score 2):

My attempted hack at using `goto`s failed because when `FOO()` isn't used, the jump label is missing for `BAR()`. But, fear not, I've come up with an even more gross hack.

You can use `#include`s instead of a macro for `FOO()` and `BAR()`. This will allow you absolute control on how the code gets expanded.

```
/* FOO file */
#define BAR_IS_BAR2
/* whatever code FOO needs to do */

/* BAR file */
#ifdef BAR_IS_BAR2
    BAR2();
    #undef BAR_IS_BAR2
#else
    BAR1();        
#endif

/*...in you source code...*/
void func1 () {
    #include "FOO"
    /*...*/
    #include "BAR"
}

void func2 () {
    #include "BAR"
}
```

Comment: OH GOD MY EYES. I thought the goto hack was bad...this is IOCCC-level bad. (Maybe that's a compliment.)

Comment: @nneonneo: It did say "Fun with macros", didn't it? :-)

Comment: +1. Too bad you cannot write `#define BAR #include "BAR"`. That would have been the ultimate precompiler hack. But sadly, this fails if there can be a function that has `"FOO"` but doesn't have `"BAR"`.